# Mesh Library for JAVA

Tags: java, mesh, triangulation

I'm looking for a library for java containing tools for mesh operations (data structures, mesh simplifying algorithms, triangulations). Somenthing like http://gts.sourceforge.net/index.html but for Java.

There was a similar question on Stack, but it was from '09 and there was no satisfying answer... so once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the [cgal-bindings](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/) project which contains SWIG bindings of the [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) library. It is working fine with Java.
For example, you'll have access to the Delaunay triangulation in 2D and 3D.